# WebApi receive parameters including dynamic list using FromBody

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to receive the below JSON format in webapi

```
    {   
    "name": "Matt",
    "age": "24",
    "payload": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
    }
```

here the payload is dynamic and it can have any key and value.

My webapi looks like

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public int age{ get; set; }
        public string payload { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Person value)
    {
      // Getting name and age but not payload.
    }
```

Questions

Is FromBody the way to get this values? If yes, what i am missing here. If no, what is the best practice for these kind of inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `[FromBody]` should be used. You can use an `IDictionary<string,string>` for payload.

```
public class Person
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public int age{ get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string,string> payload { get; set; }
}


public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Person value)
{
    var value1 = value.payload["key1"];
    var value2 = value.payload["key2"];

}
```